# How do I change the hyperlinks in Youtube with JS in a Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, youtube

```
Link = ......
let VideoTitleLink = document.querySelectorAll("#video-title-link");
let ThumbnailLink = document.querySelectorAll("#thumbnail");

for (i = 0; i < VideoTitleLink.length; i++) {
    VideoTitleLink[i].href = Link
};

for (i = 0; i < ThumbnailLink.length; i++) {
    ThumbnailLink[i].href = Link
};
```

I've made a Chrome Browser Extension which changes the hyperlinks in YouTube as some sort of prank for a friend. Strangely enough, there's a weird issue where the extension will only work if I open the links in a new tab. Any solutions to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can update URL with [chrome.tabs.update()](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-update).

`chrome.tabs.update({ 'url': Link });`

Comment: Although this is a Chrome Extension, I would like for it to be compatible with Microsoft Edge as well, and this solution won't solve that right?

Comment: And as this is the first project I've made with JS, I would like to know why the code I wrote doesn't work

Comment: @FilbertDavidTejalaksana It would be compatible with Edge AFAIK. You also use 'browser' keyword instead of 'chrome' for good measure. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/Tabs/update

Comment: currentURL = document.URL;
if (currentURL == "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ") {
} else if (currentURL.slice(0, 32) == "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=") {
     browser.tabs.update({ url: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ" })
} else {};
};

Comment: `currentURL = document.URL;
if (currentURL == currentURL) {
} else if (currentURL.slice(0, 32) == "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=") {
     browser.tabs.update({ url: currentURL})
} else {};
};`

I have made written this code. What is wrong with this?

Comment: @FilbertDavidTejalaksana You would want to create an on click event listener and update the URL.